# Cannot Center Text in CSS block using Text-Align

Tags: css, text-align

I am trying to center the words on my page. Everything is working except the text is on the left side of the screen, not the center.

```
styling{
     color: white; 
     background-color: aqua;
     font-family: 'Hachi Maru Pop', cursive; 
     font-size: 18px;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin: o auto;
     text-align: center;
  }
```

Comment: First off, `styling` is not an HTML element. Therefore no styles are being applied. If it is a class or ID, please use the appropriate selector like `.styling` for a class or `#styling` for an ID.

Comment: Please also add the HTML, as it's also not clear what tag `styling` refers to. You can also recreate your issue using https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: `margin: o auto;` --> `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: @TannerDolby That was it. Thanks! I changed it to .styling and then just added the class names in the divisions rather than creating whole blocks of code labeled <styling></styling> (which oddly enough worked for everything but centering the text).

Comment: @DylanS Your welcome. I'm glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your text element is not 100% wide. It is centering the text inside of itself already.

```css
.text {
  background-color: limegreen;
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}

.text--100 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span class="text">This is not 100%. It's an inline element.</span>
<br />
<br />
<span class="text text--100">This is 100%. Block element fills parent width.</span>
<br />
<br />
<p class="text">Paragraphs are block elements.</p>
```